# How to sort items in php table fetched from database using dropdown menu

Tags: php, sorting, drop-down-menu

I have a table with items fetched from database with various headings like `time`, `name`, `sender`, `state` `State Count` etc. ordered by descending `time`. I would like client to sort the items dynamically by ascending or descending order by choosing an option from dropdown and with a default option when the page loads.

```
    Time | Name | State | State Count | District | District Count 
    -----|------|-------|----------------------------------------
    Val1 | Val2 | Val3  | Val4        | Val5     |  Val6      
    -----|------|-------|-------------|----------|--------------
    Val7 | Val8 | Val9  | Val10       | Val11    |  Val12
```

When I tried to do this, it is not giving proper results. Is it because of the space in the value of the option ? I do not want to use Ajax, jquery and I am new to php

This is my edited code -

```
 $sql="SELECT s.time,s.code,p.name,p.state,p.district,p.assembly from Table1  
AS s INNER JOIN Table2 AS p ON s.sender=p.sender";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

$opcodey1= ($row['state']);
$opcodey2= ($row['district']);

$sql01="SELECT state  from Table2 AS r INNER JOIN Table1 AS s ON   
s.sender=r.sender and r.state='$opcodey1'";

$result01 = mysqli_query($con,$sql01);
$num01=mysqli_num_rows($result01);

$sql02="SELECT state  from Table2 AS r INNER JOIN Table1 AS s ON   
s.sender=r.sender and r.district='$opcodey2'";

$result02 = mysqli_query($con,$sql02);
$num02=mysqli_num_rows($result02);
}

echo '<form action="" method="post">';
echo '<select id="category" name="category">';
echo '<option value="s.time desc">-S.TIME DESC-</option>';

echo '<option value="s.time asc">-S.TIME asc-</option>';
echo '<option value="r.state asc">-State asc-</option>';
echo '<option value="$num01 asc">-State Count ASC-</option>';
echo '<option value="r.district asc">-District asc-</option>';
echo '<option value="$num02 asc">-District Count ASC-</option>';
echo '<br>';
echo '</select>';

echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >';
echo '<input type="button" value="Reset"     
onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href">';

echo '</form>';
echo '<br>';
if(isset($_POST['category']))
{
    $issue_opn=$_POST['category'];
}
echo "<table>
<tr>
<th>Time</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>State</th>
<th>State Count</th>
<th>District</th>
<th>District Count</th>
</tr>";
    $sqla="SELECT s.time,p.name,p.state,p.district    
           from Table1 AS s 
             INNER JOIN Table2 AS p ON s.sender=p.sender
           order by '.$issue_opn.'";
    $resulta = mysqli_query($con,$sqla);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['time'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['state'] . "</td>";
 echo '<td>.$num01."</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['district'] . " </td>";
 echo '<td>.$num02."</td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 echo "</table>";
```

Comment: First issue `order by '.$issue_opn.'";` should be `order by $issue_opn";` You would not wrap a column name in single quotes

Comment: For future reference: **DEBUGGING** echo the query and try running it via phpMyAdmin or similiar tool. Alternatively check the error status of all your calls to the database API. I do hope you are using `mysqli_` or PDO and NOT THE `mysql_` API

Comment: Thanks for responding. Please try to give an answer @RiggsFolly

Comment: You are not actually executing the first query. Look at your second query and find the statement you missed in the first

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I had missed copying some code. Please see I have edited the code and tried to include as much as of the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ajax as below. try as per below way.

```
<select id="category" name="category" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
<script>
function showUser(str)
{
  if (str=="")
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
{
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
  xmlhttp.open("GET","get_data.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

//get_data.php
<?php
include('conection.php');
$q=$_GET["q"];
$sql="SELECT s.time,p.name,p.state,p.district    
           from Table1 AS s 
             INNER JOIN Table2 AS p ON s.sender=p.sender
           order by '.$q.'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "Your data <select>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo '<option value="s.time asc">-S.TIME asc-</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

Comment: Did you not read this bit of the question _I do not want to use Ajax, jquery and I am new to php_